# Collection Utils removing duplicates object

Tags: java, performance

I have an Object Person(id, name).

```
public class Person {


/** Personid. **/
private Long personId;

/** Person Adresse. **/
private String adresse

// Getters, Setters
```

How can i remove duplicate person (who have same id) using CollectionUtils ?
For example Person1(10, aaaa), Person2(10, bbbb), Person3(20, cccc)
Result => Person1(10, aaaa), Person3(30, cccc)

EDIT :

This Solution work using Set and overrinding equals and hashcode:

```
List<Person> oldPerson = new ArrayList<>();
//oldPerson.add ...

Set<Person> newPerson = new HashSet<>(oldPerson);

List<Person> theRightPerson = new ArrayList<>(newPerson);
```

The solution that i m looking for is something like :

```
 List<Person> theRightPerson = (List<Person>) CollectionUtils.collect(oldPerson, new Transformer() {

        @Override
        public Object transform(Object input) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    })
```

Comment: duplicate (who have different id)??

Comment: same, i edit my message

Comment: Why not create a `Set`?

Comment: @RohitJain You mean with overriding `equals` method with `id` comparison in `Person` class?

Comment: override the hashCode() and equals() in Person class and use Set to have unique objects.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, it works on a list of elements like List<String> for exemple not List<Person>

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yup. Wanted OP to figure that out :)

Comment: @Anarki Then you tried in a wrong way. Show us that codes.

Comment: @RohitJain True :P. I'm little scared with that small statement :)

Comment: @Avind your idea work, but i saw a way to do this with CollectionUtils and it seems that it's a best way to do this

Comment: @Anarki May be this ??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559731/java-arraylist-copy-one-to-another-without-duplicates

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ look to my edit

Comment: @Zouzou yes and it works, just for information i m looking for a specific solution, look to the last edit

Comment: @Anarki It works or not? Because you said _"This Solution doesn't work using Set :"_.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding equals and hashcode methods and using HashSet would be easier to do. If you can't edit the source of the class, then you need to iterate over the list and compare each item based on criteria.

[How to remove duplicate objects in a List<MyObject> without equals/hashcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680157/how-to-remove-duplicate-objects-in-a-listmyobject-without-equals-hashcode)